# android display actionbar when two fragments are displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Android experts,

please help me in this issue. I have created two fragments aligned side by side for android tablet. When the user clicks on `ListView` in left side, the relevant activity is loaded on right side. Now the problem is, I want to display `action bar` in each of my activity screens, but in this screen the `ActionBar` is not seen. As I am loading fragments on `list item click`, I have my xml in this format

`<LinearLayout>`
`<FrameLayout/>` --left fragment 
`<FrameLayout/>` --right fragment 
`</LinearLayout>`

Now, if I put `ActionBar` code like

`<include android:layout="@layout/actionbar">` 
`<LinearLayout>` 
`<FrameLayout/>` --left fragment 
`<FrameLayout/>` --right fragment 
`</LinearLayout>`

This is not displaying `ActionBar` in the top. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by using `FragmentActivity`. The code is as follows,

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(FragmentA.this.getParent().getID(), mNewFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```